# Is there a method to update monthly average - weighted - from this consecutive periodic datetime time series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a dataset where start date and date is given in no particular order.
I want to create a new set of columns for months and weighted average of the data.

`del` represents no. of days in a date range

`d` is the average for that time period

```
from datetime import datetime

my_time = datetime.min.time()

from datetime import date

df1['del'] = 0

for i in range(0,df1['start'].size):

    df1['delta'][i] = (datetime.combine(df1['start'][i], my_time)-datetime.combine(df1['end'][i], my_time)).days
```

The data looks like this -

```
   in       start         end   units  del  d=(units/del)
    0  2017-11-12  2017-10-10  1207.0   33      36.575758
    1  2017-12-12  2017-11-12     5.0   30      0.166666
    2   2018-01-10  2017-12-12  8855.0  29      305.344828
    3   2018-02-08  2018-01-10  3867.0  29      133.344828
    4   2018-03-09  2018-02-08  922.0   29      31.793103
```

I want this as my final output -

```
month               d_month

Nov-17              14.7
Dec-17              ....
Jan-18              ....
```

The d_month should be computed like this -

Lets say for Nov - `(36.5757*12+0.166666*18)/30`

and so on for other months.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` directly into the dataframe.
for the below dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {
        'Start' : ['2017-11-12', '2017-12-12', '2018-01-10', '2018-02-08', '2018-03-09'],
        'End' : ['2017-10-10', '2017-11-12', '2017-12-12', '2018-01-08', '2018-02-09'],
        'Units': [1207.0, 5.0, 8855.0, 3867.0, 922.0]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

with output as

```
        Start         End   Units
0  2017-11-12  2017-10-10  1207.0
1  2017-12-12  2017-11-12     5.0
2  2018-01-10  2017-12-12  8855.0
3  2018-02-08  2018-01-08  3867.0
4  2018-03-09  2018-02-09   922.0
```

use the below code

```
df['StartM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['EndM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['Del'] = (df['StartM'] - df['EndM']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['month'] = df['StartM'].dt.strftime('%b-%y')
df['d'] = df['Units'] / df['Del']
df['d_month'] = (df['d'] * 12 + 0.166666*18) / 30
df.drop('StartM', 1, inplace=True)
df.drop('EndM', 1, inplace=True)
df
```

which results in the following output

```
Start   End     Units   Del     month   d   d_month
0   2017-11-12  2017-10-10  1207.0  33.0    Nov-17  36.575758   14.730303
1   2017-12-12  2017-11-12  5.0     30.0    Dec-17  0.166667    0.166666
2   2018-01-10  2017-12-12  8855.0  29.0    Jan-18  305.344828  122.237931
3   2018-02-08  2018-01-08  3867.0  31.0    Feb-18  124.741935  49.996774
4   2018-03-09  2018-02-09  922.0   28.0    Mar-18  32.928571   13.271428
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your input but - 
df['d_month'] = (df['d'] * 12 + 0.166666*18) / 30
For November worked because I had 12 days of November from 1st index and 18 days of November from 2nd index. I want to find out the weighted average for each month from provided unstructured date ranges.
For example if I had starting 14 days of November from 1st range and last 16 days from next range then calculation would is (36.5757*14+0.166*16)/30
del represents no. of days in a date range,d is the average for that time period.
I want to obtain monthly average from this consecutive periodic data.